# Meteor-tool error deploying with mup on digitalocean

Tags: meteor, meteor-up

I'm having an issue deploying with Mup (meteor-up) on a digital ocean (ubuntu 64) droplet. I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. I am able to run my app fine locally. Here is the error message after I `mup deploy`

Any hints as to how to fix would be great. I am running the latest meteor release (meteor@1.1.4).

```
Building Started: .
Bundling Error: code=1, error:
-------------------STDOUT-------------------

-------------------STDERR-------------------
r-tool/.1.0.38.1v7ejbf++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:317:26)
  at /Users/dm/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.1v7ejbf++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:536:24
  at runWithEnvironment (/Users/dm/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.1v7ejbf++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:136:21)
  at /Users/dm/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.1v7ejbf++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:143:14
  at /Users/dm/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.1v7ejbf++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:549:11

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/lib/build.sh: line 42: cd: /tmp/b47bd338-c403-4a29-b060-e35a51ae39be: No such file or directory
tar: bundle: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

mup log output:

```
[104.236.100.163] error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /opt/myapp/app/main.js does not exist.
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /opt/myapp/app/main.js does not exist.
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /opt/myapp/app/main.js does not exist.
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /opt/myapp/app/main.js does not exist.
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /opt/myapp/app/main.js does not exist.
```

Comment: `mup logs` data may be helpful

Comment: @Sasikanth I get the following error after applying that command: `tail: cannot open ‘/var/log/upstart/myapp.log’ for reading: No such file or directory`

Comment: https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#access-logs

Comment: No Idea, looks like same issue follow here https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/208

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the cause of the meteor build error by creating a fresh project and adding back components individually. The file that broke the build was a 3rd party plugin that I had commented out completely because it was being executed when not in use. Deleting it did the trick.

Comment: Which 3rd party plugin was causing the issue for you?

Comment: @FredrikJohansson dat.gui.js